# CUDA out of memory when training ConvLSTMD2D model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to use Keras with Tensorflow-GPU to train a 2D convolutional LSTM. The model compiles but quickly runs into out-of-memory errors when it starts training.

The model takes input in the shape of (batch_size, timesteps, 135, 240, 1), where batch_size is the number of videos and timesteps is the number of frames in a video. I lock batch_size to 1 (so one video at a time), though timesteps can vary from 600 to 4,800 frames depending on the video length.

The label shape is (batch_size, time_steps, 9), where 9 is the number of classes the model has to predict values for.

**Model Summary**

```python
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 40 59200
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 40 160
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling3d_1 (Average (None, None, 1, 1, 40)    0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, None, 40)          0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 9)           369
=================================================================
Total params: 59,729
Trainable params: 59,649
Non-trainable params: 80
```

**Device Placement Log**

```python
2018-03-28 11:40:16.994858: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-03-28 11:40:17.254698: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 970M major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.038
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 5.02GiB
2018-03-28 11:40:17.260611: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-03-28 11:40:17.520790: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4790 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2
2018-03-28 11:40:17.975718: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2
```

**Terminal Output**

If I let it run, the training session continually dumps to STDOUT in the following format:

```python
2018-03-28 11:45:29.748269: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:665] Chunk at 000000056FD23200 of size 5184000
```

It also occasionally dumps lines like these:

```python
2018-03-28 11:45:30.203961: E C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:967] failed to alloc 17179869184 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-03-28 11:45:30.209571: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 17179869184
```

[image: Screenshot of STDOUT]

I am wondering if the model is too complex or has too many layers for my GPU to handle, or if the input data for a single batch is too large. I have tried training on a GTX 970M with 6 GB of VRAM (shown above), as well as on a GTX 980 with 4 GB. My colleague has also tried running this on a GTX 1080 with 8 GB. The errors persist across all three builds.

**Edit 3/28/2018 13:20**

I should clarify a few other details. I am training the model using [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator), to which I am passing a custom subclass of [Keras.util.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence). In case it is relevant, here is the source code for my subclass:

```python
class ROASequence(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x = x_set
        self.y = y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return abs(int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size))))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x_paths = self.x[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        y_paths = self.y[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_x = []
        batch_y = []
        for xpath, ypath in zip(x_paths, y_paths):
            sample_x, sample_y = unpack_sample(xpath, ypath)
            batch_x.append(sample_x)
            batch_y.append(sample_y)
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)
        print(batch_x.shape, batch_y.shape)
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

**Edit 3/28/2018 14:00**

In the logs copied above, the CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY errors appear alongside warnings like "failed to alloc 17179869184 bytes." That's over 17 GB. What could be the main contributors to this huge memory requirement? Again, my input shape is (batch_size, time_steps, 135, 240, 1), (batch_size, time_steps, 9), where batch_size is set to 1 and time_steps has an upper bound of 4,800. I am not sure how this scales in terms of memory requirements, though, or how the ConvLSTM2D model affects it. Could it be that my Sequence subclass implementation and my use of fit_generator are causing the model to load more than one video at a time?

Comment: Can you tell CUDA version, TensorFlow-GPU version and cuDNN version?

Comment: I am using CUDA 9.0, cuDNN 7.0, and Tensorflow-GPU 1.6.0.

Comment: Did you check NVIDIA Driver correctly match with your system?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my NVIDIA driver to version 391.35, restarted, and reran. The issue persisted. What do you mean by "match up", though?

Comment: You can control allocate memory by changing parameter like `tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5)`. Otherwise it will consume total memory by default.

Comment: Controlling the per process gpu memory doesn't seem to be helping. It still appears to want to allocate more memory than is available. The console output is more or less the same as what I have shown in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was an overambitious architecture. I drastically reduced the complexity of my model, so that it looked like this:

```python
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 135, 240, 4) 736
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 135, 240, 4) 16
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling3d_1 (Average (None, None, 1, 1, 4)     0
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, None, 4)           0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 9)           45
=================================================================
Total params: 797
Trainable params: 789
Non-trainable params: 8
```

You'll see that I changed my *filter_size* value for the ConvLSTM2D from 40 to 4.

Furthermore, I clipped my video data to 100 frames per video. Thus, my input shape is now (batch_size, 100, 135, 240, 1), (batch_size, 100, 9).

After making these two changes, the model now compiles and trains without running out of memory. My next step will be to figure out how to modify my Sequence so that it splits each video into 100-frame segments (so that I don't just throw away everything after the first 100 frames). I will also probably use NumPy to downscale my frames, and there are some low-contrast frames that I could cull. However, those problems all exceed this thread's scope.